# How can I get the presentation details/rendering properties when using Find-Item command?

Tags: powershell, sitecore

I want to get the renderings (presentation details) of each items.

I have tried using `Get-Rendering`, but it doesn't work.

```
    $criteria = @(
        @{ Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_template"; Value = "{9A43A639-4209-49B9-8024-766A9E1AB03E}"; }, 
        @{ Filter = "DescendantOf"; Value = (Get-Item "master:/content/"); }
    )

    $props = @{
        Index = "sitecore_master_index"
        Criteria = $criteria
    }

    Find-Item @props | Get-Rendering -FinalLayout
```

It throws the following error:

> The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
>   either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input
>   and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take
>   pipeline input.

What am I missing?

Comment: according to the the sitecore posh module docs, the only prop of `Get-Rendering` that can accept pipeline input is the `-Item` prop & that can only accept something by value of the type `Sitecore.Data.Items.Item`, or by the prop name `Item` - [`Accept Pipeline Input? true (ByValue, ByPropertyName)`]. so ... does `Find-Item` produce such an object?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's cross posted: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17790/how-can-i-get-the-renderings-when-using-the-find-item-command